# Using Tor, could I see the IP address of my entry node with "tracert"?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, guard

Can one observe the IP address of his entry node with "tracert"? In fact, what type of information does "tracert" is able to observe on Tor network?

Answer (score 3):

Tor is only used for tunneling [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) packets. By default `traceroute` sends [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) or ICMP ([Internet Control Message Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol)) packets, ergo it can't be routed through Tor.

*However*, it's also possible to send `TCP` `SYN`'s to do essentially the same thing. If you used `traceroute` to print a series of `SYN-ACK`'s, you would see the path from the exit node to the final destination (as if you'd run the traceroute from the exit node).

(For clarification, `tracert` is a Windows only utility; every other operating system calls it `traceroute`. I have no idea if the Windows version behaves the same way as normal `traceroute`.)

If all you want to do is find the IP address of your entry node, you can simply ask Tor for information about the current streams. There should be several questions on here about how to do that, or you can use a UI such as [Arm](https://www.torproject.org/projects/arm.html.en).

Answer (score -1):

Yes your IP is exposed but not directly, i have tested and indeed, i can still see my IP amongst others. Use Tor along side a VPN (OpenVPN is great) for maximum anonymity. Tor is just more encrypted than your normal browser.

Comment: It's not clear how this answers the question, using a VPN is not always good advice, and Tor is much more than than just extra encryption.